# logstash - geoip in Kibana can not show any information using the IP addresses

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, geoip, kibana

I want to display the number of users accessing my app in a World Map using ElasticSearch, Kibana and Logstash.

Here is my log (Json format):

```
{
  "device": "",
  "public_ip": "70.90.17.210",
  "mac": "00:01:02:03:04:05",
  "ip": "192.16.1.10",
  "event": {
    "timestamp": "2014-08-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "source": "system",
    "name": "status"
  },
  "status": {
    "channel": "channelname",
    "section": "pictures",
    "downlink": 1362930,
    "network": "Wi-Fi"
  }
}
```

And this is my config file:

```
input {
  file { 
    path => ["/mnt/logs/stb.events"]
    codec => "json" 
    type => "event" 
  }
}
filter {
    date    {
        match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
    }
}

filter {
    mutate  {
        convert => [ "downlink", "integer" ]
    }
}
filter {
    geoip {
      add_tag => [ "geoip" ]
      database => "/opt/logstash/vendor/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat" 
      source => "public_ip"
      target => "geoip"
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
      add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}" ]
          }
    mutate {
      convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float" ]
    }
}
output { 
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
}
```

At the end in Kibana I see only an empty geoip tag

Can someone help me and to point me where is my mistake?

Comment: can you show the output of the rubydebug output ? 
`
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can you explain in more details how to run this, as I am not too familiar with Ruby
Thanks in advance

Comment: simply replace the output block that you have with the one from my pervious comment

Comment: OK , I added it to my logstash config file, after that I restarted the logstash (it's running OK) , and what I need to look for ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Logstash 1.3.0 you can use the geoip.location field that is created automatically instead of creating the coordinates field and converting it to float manually.

One curly bracket seems to be missing from your log, I guess this is the correct format:

```
{
    "device": {
        "public_ip": "70.90.17.210",
        "mac": "00:01:02:03:04:05",
        "ip": "192.16.1.10"
    },
    "event": {
        "timestamp": "2014-08-15T00:00:00.000Z",
        "source": "system",
        "name": "status"
    },
    "status": {
        "channel": "channelname",
        "section": "pictures",
        "downlink": 1362930,
        "network": "Wi-Fi"
    }
}
```

In this case I would suggest you to try the following configuration for the filter (without mutate):

```
filter {
    geoip {
        source => "[device][public_ip]"
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to use "geoip.location" in your map. I did quite some research and debugging to find out that in order to be resolved correctly, nested fields should be surrounded by [ ] when used as source.